# multiple-value hash common lisp

Tags: hash, tuples, common-lisp, hashtable

How can I hash pairs or triples of 'eq-able objects like symbols or ints?

In python I can use tuples as dictionary keys, is there a way to do this in lisp without resorting to an 'equal test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While some implementations might provide provisions for custom hash table functions, the standard only defines four:

> #### [18.1.1 Hash-Table Operations](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/18_aa.htm)
>
> There are four kinds of hash tables: those whose keys are compared with eq, those whose keys are compared with eql, those whose keys are
>   compared with equal, and those whose keys are compared with equalp.

That means that if you want to use the standard hash tables, then you'll probably need to use an equal or equalp hash table.  I do notice that you wrote:

> *How can I hash pairs or triples of 'eq-able objects like symbols or
>   ints?*

While symbols can be compared reliably with **eq**, you shouldn't compare numbers with **eq**.  The documentation of [**eq**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eq.htm#eq) says:

> numbers with the same value need not be eq, … An implementation is permitted to make "copies" of characters and numbers at any time. The effect is that Common Lisp makes no guarantee that eq is true even when both its arguments are "the same thing" if that thing is a character or number.

and gives this example:

```
(eq 3 3)
;   =>  true
; OR=>  false
```

However, if you *are* working with (small) tuples of integers, you could easily hash on a function of them.  E.g., the tuple (a,b,c) could be mapped to 2<sup>a</sup>×3<sup>b</sup>×5<sup>c</sup>.  Since a function like that would generate unique numbers which *are* comparable with **eql**, you could use an **eql** hash table.

Another option for such a mapping function (that would work with symbols, too) would be to use [**sxhash**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw61/CLHS/Body/f_sxhash.htm).  It's a standard hashing function that should produce identical values for **equal** values.  How it works, and what exactly it does is not really specified at all, but it has the advantage that it's stable across Lisp images of the same implementation (e.g., run one version of SBCL today and tomorrow, and **sxhash** will return the same result for an **equal** object).  Of course, it's possible that an equal-hash-table is just doing this for you already, so your mileage might vary.

Comment: Do you have an experience with [sxhash](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw61/CLHS/Body/f_sxhash.htm)? "sxhash is intended for use where the pre-defined abstractions are insufficient.". I never used it and `eql` seems sufficient here, but it might be interesting to include this function in your answer. See also: http://www.cneufeld.ca/genie/blog/2014/07/the-less-familiar-parts-of-lisp-for-beginners-sxhash/

Comment: @coredump I've read about **sxhash**, but like you, never found opportunity to use it.  Of course, since it respects **equal**, it could be that an equal-hash-table is just mapping keys to hashes with **sxhash** anyhow.

Comment: Actually, I just need a unique value for a (symbol int) pair. I can use the prime approach for the int but, can I "coerce" a symbol to a unique int?

Comment: @erjoalgo Sure, you could call sxhash on it.  But at that point, it probably makes sense to just sxhash the pair.  But at that point, it probably makes sense to just use an equal hash-table.